# Crash on assigning value to a new property using Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I basically want to increment a value on performing an action. So what I'm doing is when the action is performed  the first time, I assign the value of 1 to a new property in Realm and then I add it to the realm database.

The second time the action is performed, the max value is taken from all the values in the property and that max value is incremented by 1 and then added to the database.

But what happens is the first time itself, when I reach the line `realm.add(chatMsgObj)` a crash occurs saying `Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.`

This is the code..

```
func incrementID() -> Int {

let realm = try! Realm()
var myvalue = realm.objects(ChatMessage.self).map{$0.mainId}.max() ?? 1
myvalue = myvalue + 1
chatMsgObj.mainId = myvalue
realm.add(chatMsgObj) //CRASH HERE

return myvalue

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.

You need to open realm then write.

Read more about realm [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), and this code should work for you now.

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(chatMsgObj)
}
```

*EDIT*: from the comments below you having another problem: which is writing on the same primary key, take a peek into the documentation of realm [again](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys), and this could be a configuration problem however,

you can try to delete the application from the (Simulator/Device) that you are testing on it, and rerun the application again.

And you came a cross a

> Attempting to create an object of type 'ChatMessage' with an existing
>   primary key value '0'

so with this new crash you have 2 options.

1-  change the `PrimaryKey`  of the new object that it being written.

2- fetch the object of that `PrimaryKey` and modify it.

Now for the fetching and modifying part, take a peek on this code you should have an idea.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let myChatObject = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("youPrimaryKey == 1").first
try! realm.write {
    myChatObject!.something = newValue
}
```

Comment: try and tell me what happens gl

Comment: The control didn't go inside ` try! realm.write {
      realm.add(chatMsgObj)
    }` and crashed again saying `Attempting to create an object of type 'ChatMessage' with an existing primary key value '0'`. Elsewhere a value of 0 was already there...hence the crash I think. But if the value of 1 would have been added, then I think it would not have crashed...

Comment: well thats the right way to write on realm, use it anyway another problem is that you somehow writing the smae primary key,  try this delete the application from the simulator or the device and run again you are good to go

Comment: the answer solve this crash 100% Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction

Comment: But the control didn't go to the line `realm.add(chatMsgObj)` ..So how can the value add to the db..? Just asking since I haven't used realm before..

Comment: as first you creat an instance of realm like this ,let realm = try! Realm()
 then you use that instance to write on the realm file incase realm file couldnt be found or couldnt be open from some reason app will crash,  and some other rules we need to take into count before writing .add function like using that instance of realm open its writing closure and then adding the object inside of that.

Comment: if you are trying to add the same primary key it wont hit the add function, and it  says clearly attempting to create an object of type 'ChatMessage' with an existing primary key value '0', so instead fetch that object with that primary key and modify it. instead of adding a new object if you have to use that same key else just check on the key and change it

Comment: you know those are 2 questions, so edit your question and add the new problem after you tried the solution.